# Image Caption with python

Tags: django

I would like to ask for help on the procedure that I must follow to create a program that generates image subtitles, I have been reading about tensorflow and VGG16, but I am not sure what to do, first create a model or automatically generate the image subtitle and save it in a txt? I would appreciate the help

I have seen repositories where they only load VGG16 and tensorflow, as well as an .h5 model but I can't understand what this document would have, they also load txt files with image descriptions